# What does the following regular expression do?

Tags: regex, perl

```
foreach(@first)
{
    $first[$r] =~s/<.*>(.*)<.*>/$1/;

    $first[$r]=$1;

    $r++;
}
```

What does the regular expression do on line number 3?

Comment: First question where you get that regex

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The subtitution `s/<.*>(.*)<.*>/$1/` looks like an idiotic attempt to remove surrounding HTML tags from a string. For example, given the input

```
"<p>foo bar <em>baz</em> qux</p>"
```

we would get the output `" qux"`:

- `<.*>` matches a less-than sign, as many characters as possible, and then a greater-than sign.
- `(.*)` matches as many characters as possible and remembers the match as `$1`.
- `<.*>` matches a less-than sign, as many characters as possible, and then a greater-than sign.

Then, the whole match is replaced by the contents of capture group 1.

---

However, that code looks like it was written by someone who isn't an experienced programmer, and doesn't know much Perl anyway. Assuming that `$r = 0` before the loop, it would be equivalent to:

```
for (@first) {
    /<.*>(.*)<.*>/;
    $_ = $1;
}
```

or

```
@first = map { /<.*>(.*)<.*>/; $1 } @first;
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Match the following:

- literally `<`
- any character between 0 and unlimited times `.*`
- literally `>`
- begin capture group with backreference 1 `(`
- any character between 0 and unlimited times `.*`
- close capture group with backreference 1 `)`
- literally `<`
- any character between 0 and unlimited times `.*`
- literally `>`

#### Replace with:

`$1` the capture group with backreference 1.

---

#### Demo:

<kbd>http://regex101.com/r/iI4wB9</kbd>